# CLT for $(X_1+\cdots+X_{N_\lambda})/\sqrt{\lambda}$ for $(X_n)$ i.i.d. centered Bernouli and $N_\lambda$ independent of $(X_n)$ and Poisson$(\lambda)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

**The question follows:**

> ${[X_n]}_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence of independent rv's such that:
>
> $P(X_n=-1)=1/2$ $P(X_n=1)=1/2$
>
> Let $N \in Po(\lambda)$ where N is independent of ${[X_n]}_{n\geq1}$.
>    Set $Y = X_1 + X_2 +..+X_N$ and show that:
>
> $\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$ as $\lambda\rightarrow
> > \infty$

I've tried to take two paths.

**Path 1:**

Here my goal was to show the convergence through the use of the characteristic function.

$\varphi_{\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}(t)=E[e^{it\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}]=\sum E[e^{it\frac{X_1+X_2+\dots X_N}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}|N=n]P(N=n)= \sum E[e^{it\frac{X_1+X_2+\dots X_n}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}]P(N=n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\varphi_{\frac{X}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}(t))^nP(N=n)$

Where the C.F of X is:

$\varphi_{\frac{X}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}(t)=\frac{e^{-it}+e^{it}}{2}=cos(t)$ or one can use $\varphi_{X}(t)=\large{\frac{e^{-i\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}+e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}}{2}}=cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}})$

Thus we get:

$\varphi_{\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}))^n e^{\large{-\lambda}}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$

Now by "baking" in the lamba raised by n, $\lambda^n$, in the cosinus term raised by n using the following relation:

$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} $ I get the following:

$\varphi_{\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}(t)=e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}})}=e^{cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}})}$

And if we let $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$:

$\varphi_{\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}(t)=e^{1}$ where as the C.F of $N(0,1)$ is $\varphi (t) = e^{-t^2/2}$

**Path 2**:

The goal here is to show the convergence through the CDF.

$P(\frac{Y}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \leq y)= P(Y \leq y \sqrt{\lambda})=P(X_1+X_2+X_3 \ldots +X_N \leq y \sqrt{\lambda}  | N=n )P(N=n)=P(X_1+X_2+X_3 \ldots +X_n \leq y \sqrt{\lambda})P(N=n)$

If I haven't misinterpreted the information given then the $X's$ have the same pmf and and are independent of each other thus giving:

$P(X \leq nY\sqrt{\lambda})P(N=n)$

At this point i get stuck with the problem...what is the cdf of X? I can pretty much see the pmf of X as equal to the pmf of the symmetric bernoulli but I still can't see how I can proceed form here..

I appreciate all the help I can get and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can just condition on $\lambda=0,1,\ldots N$ for $N$ so large that $P(\lambda>N)$ is small and then apply the traditional CLT.

Comment: @ChristianRemling $\lambda$ is not random.

Comment: @Did: Yes, thanks, $\lambda\leftrightarrow N$ of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us complete Path 1: you more or less showed that $\varphi_Y(t)=\exp(-\lambda(1-\cos t))$ for every $t$. Thus, $\varphi_{Y/\sqrt{\lambda}}(t)=\exp(-\lambda(1-\cos(t/\sqrt{\lambda})))$. Now, $\cos(x)=1-\frac12x^2+o(x^2)$ when $x\to0$ hence, for every fixed $t$, when $\lambda\to\infty$, $1-\cos(t/\sqrt{\lambda})\sim t^2/(2\lambda)$, which implies that $\varphi_{Y/\sqrt{\lambda}}(t)\to\exp(-t^2/2)$, as desired.

Path 2 is more cumbersome.

Comment: Ah! How stupid I am I managed some how to cancel out the lambdas when I should have just subtracted with the terms! Also I guess one could also have solved the limit by using L'Hopitals rule, taking the derivative 2 times and set the argument in the trigonometric function to 0, which is the result of lambda going to infinity. 

Also if you don't mind how exactly is one supposed to proceed in path 2? A tip of some sort would be appreciated and thank you for the help!